# Allow one process access to /dev/uninput without completely compromising security

Tags: permissions, security

Steam In-Home-Streaming was turned back on the other day. This allows you to play games being rendered on one computer on another computer (commonly playing games on a TV/Media Centre that are being rendered on a big noisy desktop in another room). That all works great except for input.

Steam reads input on the client and sends it to the remote Steam instance. Fairly simple stuff except that in order to read the raw input and inject it at the other end, both instances of Steam [need read/write access to `/dev/uninput`](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3629-RIAV-1617#knownissues):

> In order to support streaming game controllers on a Linux host computer, /dev/uinput or /dev/input/uinput needs to be readable and writable by Steam.

This leaves me in a bit of a quandary. Do I:

- `sudo chmod o+rw /dev/uninput` to allow anything to read/write it?
- `sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/input` to allow just my user to read/write?
- Something else I'm unaware of?

Even ACL seems like it's an unneccessary security risk (any process under my user could, for example) sniff out password entry. Are there any ways of allowing just one application (like a Kernel "Capability"/FSCAP) to interact with uinput?

Comment: I am also curious about this. I am trying to stream games from my Linux desktop to my Steam OS machine in my living room. My Xbox 360 wired controller works for local games, but not streaming games.

Answer (score 2):

**OBSOLETE, read the *UPDATE* at the bottom of this reply**

You are right. This is the reason it's listed as a Known Issue. I assume they'll find a way sooner or later.

This is not secure, but it works (until there is a proper fix). 
Create a file */etc/udev/rules.d/99-steam-controller.rules* with the following content:

```
# replace game group by a valid group on your system
# Steam controller keyboard/mouse mode
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", GROUP="games", MODE="0660"

# Steam controller gamepad mode
KERNEL=="uinput", MODE="0660", GROUP="games", OPTIONS+="static_node=uinput"
```

Then add the user you use to start steam to the "games" group

```
sudo usermod -a -G games <YourUsername>
#Restart udev service
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

Source:
https://github.com/ynsta/steamcontroller

---

**UPDATE**

This has been added to the list of known issues. Make sure you are using the udev rule from the official site:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/0/490123197956024380/

There are instructions on how to fix your problem there, and the rules are updated once in a while when Valve adds support for new controllers.